# Filter table : Keep N row after each row with special value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with a huge amount of data with this structure (simplidied) :

```
+--------+-------------------------+-------+
| id     | datetime                | type  | 
+--------+-------------------------+-------+
| 1      | 2015-08-13 17:50:41     | 1     |
| 2      | 2015-08-13 17:50:45     | 0     |
| 3      | 2015-08-14 17:50:56     | 0     |
| 4      | 2015-08-14 17:50:59     | 0     |
+--------+-------------------------+-------+
```

Row with type=1 are followed by a lots of rows with type=0

I need to do an intelligent clean :

- I want to keep rows with type=0 following rows with type=1 only during one hour (After the type 1 row timestamp)
- And at least one row with type=0 per hour

I don't know if its possible to do that with a query, or if I will have to loop through all rows with a script.

I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Deleting large numbers of rows from a table with huge amounts of data is often a very time consuming effort.  Are you sure that is what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have postgres here to test, but this should return all of the data you want to keep:

```
SELECT ID FROM (
SELECT ID FROM (SELECT 
  id,
  datetime,
  type,
  LAG(type) OVER (ORDER BY id asc) AS prev_type,
  LAG(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY id asc) AS prev_date
FROM employees
WHERE 
  type=1 AND
  prev_type=0 AND
  EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (datetime - prev_date)) < 3601
  )

UNION  

SELECT MAX(ID) FROM employees GROUP BY TO_CHAR(datetime, 'DDMMYYYHH24'))
```